# percentiles of deviation

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

Disclaimer - I am an amateur and self taught in stats so I apologize if the answer is painstakingly obvious.

From what I've read, the average can sometimes hide data regarding extreme values and that the use of percentiles is better for capturing these anomalies, but it seems that standard deviation is a lot like the mean in the fact that (if I'm not mistaken) you get the average deviation from the mean but no idea about extreme values or frequency of said values.

For this reason is there a term analogous to the median of the data that describes the different percentiles of deviations from the mean? And is there a term for the frequency that each percentile occurs?

Answer (score 1):

You are totally right in your assessment that the standard deviation, just like the mean, is just one number and can therefore not tell you everything about how the entire distribution looks like. If you would have for example the 25%, 50% (median) and 75% percentile, you would have a lot more information about that distribution but the picture is still incomplete. If you have the 1%, 2%, ... 99% percentiles you know the distribution more than accurately enough for most practical purposes. Nevertheless, even in that case, some distributions really defy characterisation by percentiles alone. I could give you examples of two distributions with the same 1% up to 99% percentiles but having entirely different means and/or variances, even to the point where these quantities do not exist any more. The difference then is in the shape of their tails. But this would lead us into the wondrous world of heavy-tailed, long-tailed, power-tailed, etc. distributions.